# Fade smoothly between gradients

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

The following code should fade a rectangle smoothly between two gradients:

```
public class FXTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(200, 100, new LinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 1, true, CycleMethod.REPEAT, new Stop(0, Color.BLACK), new Stop(1, Color.RED)));
        root.getChildren().add(rect);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        getFillTimeline(rect, new LinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 1, true, CycleMethod.REPEAT, new Stop(0, Color.RED), new Stop(1, Color.BLACK))).play();
    }

    private Timeline getFillTimeline(Shape node, Paint newPaint) {
        Timeline t = new Timeline();
        t.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(node.fillProperty(), node.getFill())));
        t.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3), new KeyValue(node.fillProperty(), newPaint)));
        return t;
    }
}
```

If I specify plain colours in the above example, then the fade occurs no problem, nice and smoothly. However, if I use gradients (as in the code above) then no fade occurs, the gradient just switches suddenly after 3 seconds (or whatever the duration of the timeline is.)

How can I achieve a gradual fade when utilising a gradient rather than a simple colour? Is there some logic I'm missing behind why this isn't meant to work the way I'm thinking, or is it a bug?

In either case, what would be the best workaround to achieve this effect?

Comment: Did you file it on JavaFX Jira? If yes can you post its ticket number here too. Also have you tried FadeTransition?

Comment: @UlukBiy FadeTransition is actually my current workaround, but requires two nodes (rectangles in this case) since it changes the opacity - in a SSCCE this is fine but gets rather annoying in more complex examples.

As for the Jira ticket: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-33193

Comment: Jira says not a bug: "Timeline can interpolate only numerical values or values that implement Interpolatable interface (like Color). LinearGradient does not implement such interface as they are multiple way how to interpolate between two LinearGradients. You'd need to implement this yourself by overriding Transition, computing and setting the value inside overriden "interpolate" method."

Personally I disagree, I think it'd be much more sensible to choose a default implementation so there's at least some sensible transition there, but seems it's not going to change for a while!

Answer (score 1):

I don't suppose it would know how to make the smooth transition between to fundamentally different paints. Try setting up the solid color as a gradient, where both start- and end- color are of same color.

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer - but even when the paints are both linear gradients, it still doesn't fade (just switches suddenly when the timeline finishes.)